# Help thinking through "Proving Inequalities by Induction" question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on an inequality induction proof (part of the inductive step shown):

[image: Inductive Step of Induction Proof]

I'm finding my though process is stuck and am not making forward progress. I'm hoping someone can help me think things through a little bit more to get my brain jogging so I can solve the problem. The part I'm stuck at is understanding how to apply the inductive hypothesis.

I see this connection: $$\sum_{j=1}^n\left ( \frac{1}{j^2} \right )+\frac{1}{n^2}\geq \sum_{j=1}^n\left ( \frac{1}{j^2} \right )$$

I also see this connection:
$$2-\frac{1}{n}\ge2-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Of course, I'm iffy about those connections, but that is something I'm identifying, whether it's correct or not. Either way, I cannot really seem to get beyond this and being able to apply any connections I do see.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you, all.

Comment: You assume the inequality for $n$ (I assume you have done the base case already). Then, you add $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ on both sides. On the left, we have the sum for $n+1$. If you now can show that $$2-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\le 2-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ you are done because the hypothesis for $n+1$ holds due to the transitivity of "$\le$"

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to change the $$\frac{1}{n^2}$$ on the left side to $$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$. That said, why did you replace the sum with $$2-\frac{1}{n}$$? That was something I thought about doing, but wasn't sure it could be done.

Comment: We can use that the sum upto $n$ is less than or equal to $2-1/n$ (we have no equality however). Adding the term for $n+1$ does not change the situation. We still can assume the inequality. And if this expression is smaller than $2-1/(n+1)$ , then the sum must be it as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you for your help. Now I've been stuck trying to figure out how to show the inequality is true. No matter how I've worked it, I can't seem to get to anything that seems obvious to me that it's true. Maybe a piece of information is missing that I need to extrapolate from the other data?

Comment: Can I use the fact that: $$\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ 

or:
$$2-\frac{1}{n} < 2-\frac{1}{n+1} $$ 

somehow?

Comment: To show the inequality in my above comment , just mutliply both sides with $n(n+1)^2$ and simplify. You will see that the left side is always $1$ less than the right side. Hence the inequality must be true for every positive integer $n$

Comment: We can even say that the inequality is strict for $n\ge 2$, but that need not be shown in this exercise.